# tkinter - problem with a coloring a rectangle in a grid made out of rectangles

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a pathfinding algorithm in python. The user is supposed to select a starting point by hovering the mouse of a field and pressing <kbd>s</kbd>. The field should now change the color.

However, I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I am only able to color to color the fields from top left corner to the bottom right corner. In the code, Im printing out the `objectID` in console, which shows that there is maybe something wrong with the way of how I created the rectangles.

I'm creating the rectangles in the `draw_grid` method in the `Window` class and coloring the fields in the `select_start_node` method.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 600
        self.width = 600
        self.grid_list = {x for x in range(0, 600)}
        self.grid = []
        self.grid_dict = {}
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x600")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.width,
                                height=self.height, background="white")
        self.canvas.bind("s", self.select_start_node)
        self.canvas.bind("<1>", lambda event:
        self.canvas.focus_set())

    def draw_grid(self):
        print(self.grid)
        for x in self.grid_list:
            if x % 30 == 0:
                self.grid.append(x)
            else:
                pass
        print(self.grid)

        for x in self.grid:
            for y in self.grid:
                print(x, y+30)
                rec = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, x, y+30, y+30)

        self.canvas.pack()

    def select_start_node(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)
        x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        item = self.canvas.find_closest(x, y)
        p = self.canvas.coords(item)
        print(item)
        print(p)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(p[0], p[0], p[0]+30, p[0]+30, fill="red")


def main():
    node_list = []
    cord_list = []
    window = Window()
    window.draw_grid()
    window.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the entire design of you game, but suggest that you do things differently with respect to the grid of rectangles. In the code below `self.grid` is a 2-dimensional list-of-lists and each entry is a `Canvas` rectangle object. This make selecting and changing one of them relatively each because `canvas.find_closest(x, y)` will give you the object id of the associated rectangle object directly, which makes changing its fill color trivial.

Because of that, I also changed it so you can just click on one of the rectangles to change it instead of moving the mouse cursor and then pressing a key.

Also note that I also got rid of most those hardcoded numerical constants you were using all over the place, which makes the code more flexible in case you decide to change one of them at a later time.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cell_size = 30
        self.height = 600
        self.width = 600
        self.hz_cells = self.width // self.cell_size  # Number of horizontal cells.
        self.vt_cells = self.height // self.cell_size  # Number of vertical cells.

        # Preallocate 2D grid (list-of-lists).
        self.grid = [[None for _ in range(self.hz_cells)] 
                               for _ in range(self.vt_cells)]
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("%sx%s" % (self.width, self.height))
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.width,
                                height=self.height, background="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("<1>", self.select_start_node)

#        You can still do it this way if you want.
#        self.canvas.bind("s", self.select_start_node)
#        self.canvas.bind("<1>", lambda event: self.canvas.focus_set())    

    def draw_grid(self):
        """ Fill Canvas with a grid of white rectangles. """
        for i in range(self.hz_cells):
            x = i * self.cell_size
            for j in range(self.vt_cells):
                y = j * self.cell_size
                self.grid[i][j] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                    x, y, x+self.cell_size, y+self.cell_size, fill="white")

    def select_start_node(self, event):
        """ Change the color of the rectangle closest to x, y of event. """
        x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        selected_rect = self.canvas.find_closest(x, y)
        if selected_rect:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(selected_rect, fill="red")  # Change color.


def main():
    node_list = []
    cord_list = []
    window = Window()
    window.draw_grid()
    window.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you martineau for your answer and all the improvements in the code:)

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Very impressed with your coding so far. Have fun developing your game!